# Iteration over list while adding and removing elements

Tags: c++, 3d

I'm having trouble with list iteration while inserting/erasing elements.

What I'm trying to achieve is iterate over the list but ignore freshly added elements.

I've tried to do it by pushing new elements at the front and going to the next element when erasing.

The problem is it doesn't seem to work. Iteration completely changes when I add new elements.

Here's the code:

```
void addTriangle(Vec3f v0, Vec3f v1, Vec3f v2){
  vertices.push_back(v0);
  vertices.push_back(v1);
  vertices.push_back(v2);
  int n = vertices.size();
  faces.push_front(face(&vertices[n-1], &vertices[n-2], &vertices[n-3]));
}
void clip(vector<Plane*> planes){ 
  for(auto s:planes){
    auto i = faces.begin();
    while(i != faces.end() && !faces.empty()){
      Vec3f p0 = *(i->v0), p1 = *(i->v1), p2 = *(i->v2);
      vector<Vec3f> interPoints;
      Vec3f res;
      if(planeSegmentIntersection(p0, p1, s, res)) interPoints.push_back(res);
      if(planeSegmentIntersection(p1, p2, s, res)) interPoints.push_back(res);
      if(planeSegmentIntersection(p2, p0, s, res)) interPoints.push_back(res);
      if(interPoints.size() == 0){
        if(s->n*p0 + s->d < 0){
          i = faces.erase(i);
        }
      } else if(interPoints.size() == 2){
        vector<Vec3f> newPoints;
        if(s->n*(p0 - s->p) > 0) newPoints.push_back(p0);
        if(s->n*(p1 - s->p) > 0) newPoints.push_back(p1);
        if(s->n*(p2 - s->p) > 0) newPoints.push_back(p2);
        if(newPoints.size() == 2){
          Vec3f further = (interPoints[0]-newPoints[0]).norm() < (interPoints[1]-newPoints[0]).norm() ? interPoints[1] : interPoints[0];
          Vec3f closer = (interPoints[0]-newPoints[0]).norm() < (interPoints[1]-newPoints[0]).norm() ? interPoints[0] : interPoints[1];
          this->addTriangle(newPoints[0], further, newPoints[1]);
          this->addTriangle(newPoints[0], further, closer);
        } else if(newPoints.size() == 1){
          this->addTriangle(newPoints[0], interPoints[0], interPoints[1]);
        }
        i = faces.erase(i);
      } else i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the info available, but for example storing `&vertices[n-1]` somewhere depends on vertices being extremely stable. If it happens to be a vector, the next `push_back` might invalidate the pointer.

Comment: Checking `faces.empty()` in your outer `while` is redundant and can be removed. More importantly, in the `if(interPoints.size() == 0)` block (FYI, use `empty()` here instead), if the inner `if` evaluates as false, you are not incrementing `i` for the next loop iteration

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! I completely missed that. It solves the problem.